# Unable to install and run App/Panel Indicator in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, python, ppa, indicator, packaging

I have developed an app indicator for Ubuntu 14.04 using Python. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.ebower.com/docs/ubuntu-ppa/) and I was able to push my app indicator to my PPA successfully. When I run the following commands -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mayank26saxena/hn-indicator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hn-indicator
```

The app indicator gets installed successfully but it doesn't show up in the notification tray automatically. When I click on the dash and search for the keyword "Indicator" my app indicator doesn't show up. I am unable to run it after installation.

Can somebody tell me what I am missing out on?

Here is the code for my indicator - https://github.com/mayank26saxena/hn-indicator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing:

- A `.desktop` file to be installed in `/usr/share/applications/` for Dash/App Menu listing/launching.

  An icon to be installed in `/usr/share/icons/` for this `.desktop` launcher.
- Another little bit different `.desktop` file to be installed in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` for session autostart.

XD I will not give you examples! You know why?

Update to fix OP modifications:

- **`hn-indicator/debian/install`** missing the binary indicator file, com'n it is the heart of this package :). Source path wrong, you don't have a `src/` folder. Plus a typo in icon name `.ong`→`.png`.

  ```
  hn-indicator.desktop /usr/share/applications/
  hackernews.png /usr/share/icons/
  hn /usr/bin/
  ```
- **`hn-indicator/hn-indicator.desktop`** wrong launching command `Exec=application`

  ```
  Exec=/usr/bin/hn
  ```
- ## Missing shebang #!

  As header of **`hn`**

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python2
  ```

Comment: Do I need to have a debian/install file as well which will include the directories where the above 3 files will be saved into?

Comment: @MayankSaxena, Yes if you are looking for simple way (Debian package only)). But If you want your user to be able to install it from the source archive too, you may look for writing  a Makefile later.

Comment: Oh, alright. This is my [hn-indicator.desktop](https://github.com/mayank26saxena/hn-indicator/blob/master/hn-indicator.desktop) file and this is my [debian/install](https://github.com/mayank26saxena/hn-indicator/blob/master/debian/install) file. Are these good to go or do I need to make some changes? I don't want the indicator to autostart so I have not added that file.

Comment: @MayankSaxena updated the answer.